# How to print each digit of the number different from the one that precedes it?

Tags: go, digits

For example, if I have the number 35565, the output is 3565.

So, my snippet gets single digits, but I don't know how to keep previous digit to check it with the next one.

```
for {
num = num / 10
fmt.Print(num)
        
if num/10 == 0 {
    break
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Initialize a variable to store the previously computed value 2. Compare the num against the value in previously computed value 3. Print if they are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach breaks down a number into its digits from right-to-left, storing them as a slice of ints, then iterates those digits from left-to-right to build up the number with "sequentially unique" digits.

I originally tried to break down the number from left-to-right but couldn't figure out how to handle place-holding zeroes; breaking it down from right-to-left, I know how to capture those zeroes.

```golang
// unique removes sequences of repeated digits from non-negative x,
// returning only "sequentially unique" digits:
// 12→12, 122→12, 1001→101, 35565→3565.
//
// Negative x yields -1.
func unique(x int) int {
    switch {
    case x < 0:
        return -1
    case x <= 10:
        return x
    }

    // -- Split x into its digits
    var (
        mag     int   // the magnitude of x
        nDigits int   // the number of digits in x
        digits  []int // the digits of x
    )

    mag = int(math.Floor(math.Log10(float64(x))))
    nDigits = mag + 1

    // work from right-to-left to preserve place-holding zeroes
    digits = make([]int, nDigits)
    for i := nDigits - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        digits[i] = x % 10
        x /= 10
    }

    // -- Build new, "sequentially unique", x from left-to-right
    var prevDigit, newX int

    for _, digit := range digits {
        if digit != prevDigit {
            newX = newX*10 + digit
        }
        prevDigit = digit
    }

    return newX
}
```

Here's a [Go Playground with a test](https://go.dev/play/p/aIBUTe7afbj).

This could be adapted to deal with negative numbers by flipping the negative sign at the beginning and restoring it at the end.